# Arrays are really homogeneous?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, collections

In the below code, EX1 and EX 2 prov the homogeneous theory but in EX3 it holds multiple types values. So then, how we can say arrays are homogeneous? What is the exact theory behind this?

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Ex 1
            int [] intArr = new int[5];
            intArr[0] = 1;
            intArr[1] = 2;

            // Ex 2
            int [] intArr2 = new int[5];
            intArr2[0] = 1;
            intArr2[1] = "ss";

            // Ex 3
            Object [] objArr = new Object[5];
            objArr[0] = 1;
            objArr[1] = "ss";
            objArr[3] = new Object();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You declared EX3 as an array of Objects and java's syntax sugar allowed you not to declare 1 and "ss" as `Object` explicitly (just like autoboxing and unboxing works with `Integer <-> int`). But they are casted to an `Object` when added to an array so array stays homogeneous. It contains only values of type `Object`

Comment: [You can't assign a String to an int array](http://rextester.com/OJP27372).  Did you test your code before posting this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think that's part of OPs point that arrays are homogeneous, OP should mark Ex 2 as causing a compile error.

Comment: @xtratic Yes, after seeing Random Guy's comment, I understood the question.

Comment: @Sandun Perera In Ex 3, `objArr[0]` contains an `Integer`, which is an `Object`, boxed from an `int`; `objArr[1]` contains a `String` which is an `Object`; and `objArr[3]` contains an `Object` which is clearly an `Object`. So you have an array full of `Objects`.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen : Yap, Ex1 and EX3 working fine. EX2 has compilation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a two concepts here: inheritance and auto-boxing

**[Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) -**
A String inherits from Object and hence is an Object. This means that String gets all methods and properties defined in the Object class automatically at compile time. It is an Object plus additional stuff that is specific to the String. However, it can be viewed by Java as an Object because it is an Object. When it is added to the array, it is added as an Object, not as a String. That is because the Array is defined as an Array of objects.

```
char a = "ss".charAt(1);   // Legal as charAt(..) is a method in the String class
Object [] objArr = new Object[5];
objArr[1] = "ss";  
objArr[1].charAt(1);       // Not legal because charAt(..) method is not defined for Object
```

See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

**[Auto-Boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Autoboxing) -**
Java performs a shortcut known as auto-boxing to a automatically convert primitives to a special set of wrapper Classes all of which inherit from Object. Hence, because of auto-boxing and inheritance, assigning a number to an Object will convert that number to an Object as well.

Hence, everything added to the array was added as an Object. It is true that the objects in the array may be classes that inherited from Object. However, as far as the array is concerned, they are of type Object. Even so, if you were to pull it out of the array and cast it as an Integer, you could do so. It still carries the Integer information with it but that information in not available without a cast. From the array's point of view, it is only an Object.

See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: Thanks I got your point. Did you mean number 1 (int) converts to Integer (Wrapper class) 1 and it converts again to Object when adding to the array?

Comment: Almost. It converts 1 to an Integer wrapper class. However, when it adds it to the array, I wouldn't say it converts it. This is where it gets a 
bit more confusing. It adds it to the array as an Object. However, if you were to pull it out of the array and cast it as an Integer, you could do so. It still carries the Integer information with it but that information in not available with a cast. From the array's point of view, it is only an Object.

Comment: @LiveNLearn I suggest you incorporate that comment into your Answer, as a an important point.

Comment: Thanks all. @LiveNLearn I think I got your point? Is there any possibility to understand what's happening here by analysing the byte code?